# reload the image after editing in jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have an image editing page with the parameters being send via ajax. So editing page edits the image but I'd like to reload the same image without reloading the page. I've tried removing src and adding it back, but it adds the unedited image.

For example, if I send the parameter to crop the image by 100px, it would crop the image, but on page it would still be the same. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: any code to show,  na?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your browser caches the image, and so even if you change the src, the image is not downloaded again. A fix to this is, other than changing the image name, is to add a random value, like a timestamp to your src.

```
img.src = `${url}?timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`;
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!!!